# Automatically Interacting With JavaScript on a Webpage

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, html

So I have been using Selenium for a few days to control webpages (filling in forms, going from one page to another, etc), but I have come across a problem I can't figure out.

It's one thing to send information to a web page that is built in HTML. In that case I have access to all the parts of the page (at least in most cases) through the HTML code (usually tags), but when forms and other parts of the page is written in JavaScript I have no idea how to access the different elements. For a web page with HTML I usually do something like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement element;

driver.get("https://somepage.com");
element = driver.findElement(By.name("email_address"));
element.sendKeys("somename@gmail.com");
element = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
element.sendKeys("pass");
element.submit();
```

But this does not work on a page where the elements are made using JavaScript. Any suggestions?

Comment: So your basic question is: "how to test javascript logic using selenium". IF it is possible, Google will know. Its a very difficult problem to solve however, considering that browsers have turned into complex machines of their own just to be able to properly and efficiently run javascript logic.

Comment: "Made using JavaScript"???...well they are still elements within the DOM. It doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok, but how do I find out what the elements are named, or how do I access the elements? With a regular HTML site it's quite easy, but with this site I'm trying I have tried all that is written about accessing elements in the Selenium site without any success.